# How to exclude the checkbox from the handleClick event when the area is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If the user clicks on the checkbox, I don't want the handleClick to be fired.

Is there a way to exclude it or ignore the click?

```
<div ...  onClick={this.handleClick}>
  <div>
    some content here
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike"> I have a bike
  </div>
</div>
```

My click function is:

```
 handleCardClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
 }
```

I can put some class on the checkbox if required.

Comment: Try adding `onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}` to the checkbox.

Comment: @ChrisG but I only want to stop if the checkbox was clicked

Comment: Which is exactly what my suggestion does. Add it to the checkbox, and the event will not bubble up to the div: https://codesandbox.io/s/6v9vorn33w (check the console)

Comment: @Blankman why don't you put `onChange` on input element and stopPropagation there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.stopPropagation() inside function that called on onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the click of the checkbox using the `srcElement` object:

First apply class on the checkbox:

```html
<div (click)="onClick($event)">
    <input type="checkbox" class="no-click" />
</div>
```

```js
onClick(event) {
   if(event.srcElement.classList.contains("no-click")) {
     return false; // don't execute the function more if element has no-click class
   }
}

// Your other logic
```

The above logic is based on the angular 4.